# JSF2 and Richfaces 3.3.3 application on tomcat 6.0 crashes with a StackOverflowError

Tags: richfaces, jsf-2, tomcat6

I am using JSF 2 and richfaces 3.3.3 for an application hosted on tomcat 6.0.20. 
The application crashes as soon as a request is made via the browser (Mozilla and IE).

My web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

 <display-name>TestJSF</display-name>

 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>pages/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <context-param>
  <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
  <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
  <param-value>server</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.DISABLE_FACELET_JSF_VIEWHANDLER</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
  <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING</param-name>
  <param-value>enable</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
  <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <listener>
  <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

 <filter>
  <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
  <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
 </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

The exception is

```
    javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
 org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:530)
 com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:542)
 com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:359)
 com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:150)
 com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:190)
 com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:127)
 org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
 org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:117)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:309)
```

The stack trace is recursively logged with this until the StackOverflowError occurrs.

If I remove all the configurations related to Richfaces, the application works like charm.
Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, change this section...

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

the faces servlet should be mapped to *.jsf, or just the /faces/*.  Then disable the faces servlet that is builtin to JSF2...

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DISABLE_FACELET_JSF_VIEWHANDLER</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And now include the original facelets jar... it should be like version 1.1.15 or something.  Whats going on here is that JSF 1.x didn't have a dedicated view technology and despite most people using JSP, it had some serious shortcomings.  As a result facelets was integrated into JSF2 as the dedicated view technology.  The issue is that RichFaces 3.x doesn't fully support JSF2 yet, specifically it still has dependancies on the independant facelets project.  So as a result, you have to disable the builtin facelets, and include the independant version of facelets.  Alternativly, RichFaces4 just came out with Milestone 5, which is really close to the Candidate release (and then stable build), and it should be fully integrated with JSF2

Answer (score 1):

I am using JSF 2.0 and Richfaces 3.3.3.Final with the following configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Working JSF2/Richfaces3.3 Config</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.LifecycleProvider</param-name>
        <param-value>org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.NoInjectionAnnotationLifecycleProvider</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SECRET</param-name>
        <param-value>NzY1NDMyMTA=</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ERROR_HANDLING</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>    
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>    
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.validateXml</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.verifyObjects</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.VIEW_HANDLERS</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.COMPRESS_SCRIPT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.COMPRESS_STYLE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.xmlparser.ORDER</param-name>
        <param-value>TIDY</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING</param-name>
        <param-value>enable</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadStyleStrategy</param-name>
        <param-value>NONE</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadScriptStrategy</param-name>
        <param-value>ALL</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DISABLE_FACELET_JSF_VIEWHANDLER</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <display-name>Ajax4jsf Filter</display-name>
        <filter-name>ajax4jsf</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>createTempFiles</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceparser</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>enable-cache</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>        
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ajax4jsf</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Everything working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you are using JSF 2 and RichFaces 3.3.3?  For JSF 2, you should use RichFaces 4.